# How to repeat the same number in a for loop like (7,7,6,6,5,5,4,4)?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I was learning on [jsdares](https://jsdares.com/) and it told me to move a robot in a spiral like maze and the spacing between each turn would be (7,7,6,6,5,5,4,4.....) but every time it would drive it would hit the wall and print out (7,6,5,4...). Any help guys?
Also: i need it to stop at 0 which it would hit "goal block"

EDIT: I can't add arrays because it would be input back in to the robots `forwardRight` function.

```js
function forwardRight(distance) {
  robot.drive(distance);
  robot.turnRight();
}

for (var k = 7; k <= 14; k++) {
  forwardRight(k);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're trying to ask is that you want to repeat the given action for each `k` value?

If so, you can just call the function a second time in each loop:

```js
function forwardRight(distance) {
  robot.drive(distance);
  robot.turnRight();
}

for (var k = 7; k <= 14; k++) {
  forwardRight(k);
  forwardRight(k);
}
```

---

Looking at the specific problem on [jsdares](https://jsdares.com/?dare=300000000000000000000007), you have a few other problems in your code. Your `for` loop is *incrementing* `k` when it should be *decrementing* until 0:

```js
function forwardRight(distance) {
  robot.drive(distance);
  robot.turnRight();
}

for (var k = 7; k > 0; k--) {
  forwardRight(k);
  forwardRight(k);
}
```

---

Testing this out in this very specific environment still causes the robot to run into the wall. The reason for this is because of the length of the first three `drive` calls should be 7. Your pattern of (7,7,6,6,5,5,4,4,...) just needs an additional `forwardRight(7)` prior to entering the loop:

```js
function forwardRight(distance) {
  robot.drive(distance);
  robot.turnRight();
}

forwardRight(7);

for (var k = 7; k > 0; k--) {
  forwardRight(k);
  forwardRight(k);
}
```

Since it scores based on lines with actual content, the empty lines won't matter. This was also the shortest I could come up with that it would also accept as a solution.

Answer (score -1):

Check this:

```js
var inc = 1;
var array = [];
for (var i = 7; i <= 14; ) {
    if (inc == 0) {
        inc = 1;
    } else {
        i++;
        inc = 0;
    }
    array.push(i);
}
 console.log(array);
```

Comment: invalid syntax at the parentheses after the 14

Comment: your for loop only has 2 operators

Comment: also u cant do arrays

Comment: @Zoned _“your for loop only has 2 operators”_. This is so wrong that I just have to comment… His _head_ of the `for` loop has two parts called the _initialization_ and the _condition_. Operators are `=` and `<=`, which are in fact two operators, but the number of operators is completely irrelevant. The “missing” thing you’re wondering about is called the _final expression_. This one is optional. By the way, the two other parts are _also_ optional. [Re-read how a `for` loop works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).